# merge two queries from two tables as a one struct

Tags: mysql, postgresql, go

I have a struct called  Ads

```
type Ads struct {
    ID      int `json:"id"`
    Subject string `json:"subject"`
    Phone   string `json:"phone"`
}

func GetAdsPostgres() (ads []Ads, err error) {
    ads = make([]Ads, 0)
    rows, err := db1.Query("Select ad_id, subject FROM ads limit 200 ")
    for rows.Next() {
        var ad Ads
        rows.Scan(&ad.ID, &ad.Subject)

        test := reflect.ValueOf(ad.ID)
        addd := test.Interface().(int)
        rows1, _ := db1.Query("Select phone FROM ads where ad_id=$1", addd)
        rows1.Scan(&ad.Phone)

        ads = append(ads, ad)
        rows1.Close()
    }

    if err = rows.Err(); err != nil {
        return
    }
    return
}
```

without thinking of join the table because the phone has multipte enumeration values which I have to reform them as fields after

Comment: Your `if err = rows.Err(); err != nil { return }` is entirely unnecessary. No need for an `if ... { return } return`.  Just do `return`.

Comment: @Flimzy for the phone is having an enumeration value : local , regional , international with each value so i created a struct having all the fields with the phone enumeration that's why i have to follow this method

Comment: @dev_medo: That's irrelevant to my point.  Having an "if x do y else do y" is identical to just "y"

Answer (score 3):

Just get the phone number too in the first query; don't repeat yourself.

```
db1.Query("Select ad_id, subject, phone FROM ads limit 200 ")
```

Comment: for the phone is have an enumeration value : local , regional , international with each value so i created  a struct having all the fields with the phone enumeration  that's why i have to follow this method